# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined using a for loop to search an array

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project where I make a table in HTMl and than draw the table in javascript using a 2D Array. Then I made a function that finds a * and makes them into letters where other * are touching it. Than once that is done is changes the letter to B and finds the next * in the array and makes all * touching it into B and so on. My problem is that my loop that finds all the * in the array comes up with an error. Any suggestions?

```
 var organismArray = [
    ["*","*","_"],
    ["-","_","*"],
    ["-","*","*"]
]; 

function drawOrganism() {
    var letter = 'A';
    var Organisms = 0;
    for (var col = 0; col < 2; col++) {
        for (var row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
            if (organismArray[col][row] == "*") { // This is where the Error occurs.
                organismArray = howManyOrganisms(col, row, letter);
                letter++;
                Organisms++;


            }`
        }
    }
    console.log(organismArray);
}
function howManyOrganisms(col,row,letter) {
    organismArray[col][row] = letter;


    if (col + 1 < organismArray.length) {
        if (organismArray[col + 1][row] == "*") {
            howManyOrganisms(col + 1, row, letter);
        }
    }
    if (col - 1 >= 0) {
        if (organismArray[col - 1][row] == "*") {
            howManyOrganisms(col-1, row, letter);
        }
    }
    if (row - 1 >= 0) {
        if (organismArray[col][row - 1] == "*") {
            howManyOrganisms(col, row - 1, letter);
        }
    }
    if (row + 1 < organismArray[col].length) {
        if (organismArray[col][row + 1] == "*") {
            howManyOrganisms(col, row + 1, letter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the for loops, if the condition is met, you re-assign the result of a void function to the original organism array.

```
if (organismArray[col][row] == "*") {
  organismArray = howManyOrganisms(col, row, letter);
}
```

The 'howManyOrganisms' function never returns anything, therefore, you're wiping the original organismArray.

So maybe try this:

```
if (organismArray[col][row] == "*") {
   howManyOrganisms(col, row, letter);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much!! That fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `return` keyword in the `howManyOrganisms()` function, therefore this line:

```
organismArray = howManyOrganisms(col, row, letter);
```

assigns `undefined` to the `organismArray`. You have to add `return` to each of the recurrent calls and also at the end of the `howManyOrganisms()` function because it not always will end up in one of the `if`s. Try this one:

```js
 var organismArray = [
    ["*","*","_"],
    ["-","_","*"],
    ["-","*","*"]
]; 

drawOrganism();

function drawOrganism() {
    var letter = 'A';
    var Organisms = 0;
    for (var col = 0; col < 2; col++) {
        for (var row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
            if (organismArray[col][row] == "*") {
                organismArray = howManyOrganisms(col, row, letter);
                letter++;
                Organisms++;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(organismArray);
}
function howManyOrganisms(col,row,letter) {
    console.log("workig");
    organismArray[col][row] = letter;


    if (col + 1 < organismArray.length) {
        if (organismArray[col + 1][row] == "*") {
            return howManyOrganisms(col + 1, row, letter); // return here
        }
    }
    if (col - 1 >= 0) {
        if (organismArray[col - 1][row] == "*") {
            return howManyOrganisms(col-1, row, letter); // return here
        }
    }
    if (row - 1 >= 0) {
        if (organismArray[col][row - 1] == "*") {
            return howManyOrganisms(col, row - 1, letter); // return here
        }
    }
    if (row + 1 < organismArray[col].length) {
        if (organismArray[col][row + 1] == "*") {
            return howManyOrganisms(col, row + 1, letter); // return here
        }
    }
    
    return organismArray; // and return here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That fixed it!

Comment: Glad I could help! If you found it useful, consider marking this as an answer so the future readers could benefit from it. That's how SO works ;)